# Using dagrejs.js unable to start react app, running into error Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, babel-loader, react-flow, dagre

Using Node version v14.17.1, babel-loader version 8.1.0

```
./node_modules/@dagrejs/graphlib/lib/graph.js 18:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (18:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js  
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|
| class Graph {
>   #isDirected = true;
|   #isMultigraph = false;
|   #isCompound = false;
```

Tried using webpack to exclude node_modules/.
Tried updating the node version to v17.0.0

Comment: A solution to this issue can be found here: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/you-may-need-an-additional-loader-to-handle#:~:text=The%20error%20%22You%20may%20need,json%20file.

Updating tsconfig.json to set target to ES6 worked.